# What is meant by reading data in a machine-independent way?

Tags: java, sockets

1. The DataInputStream class's documentation says that it is able to
   read the data in a machine-independent way , what exactly does that
   mean ?
2. Does it mean it will receive the exact same data regardless
   of , in what programming language the other end of the Socket
   communication is written ?
3. Is the DataInputStream useful for reading
   primitives sent from an application/program written in other
   language(e.g. if a C application is sending and a Java application
   is receiving)  if not which class would ?

Comment: I think it's about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). So if process A running on big-endian plaform write data using DataOutputStream, then process B running on little-endian platform should be able to read it using DataInputStream.

Answer (score 2):

The DataInputStream works on a sequence of bytes. When it reads larger values from such a sequence, it uses a fixed interpretation. For example, when reading an int, which requires 4 bytes, it reads them in big-endian format. That is, if the byte stream contains `0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67`, the DataInputStream will read this as the integer `0x01234567`.

In short, it uses a fixed [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) instead of relying on the endianness of the platform.

Plus, it defines the exact size and representation of several data types, whose sizes depend on the execution environment in other programming languages. For example, int C the type `int` is *at least 16 bits wide*, while Java defines it as *exactly 32 bits wide*, and so does Java's DataInputStream.

The DataInputStream is great when you need to exchange data between Java programs. If you need to exchange data between different programming languages, you should use another library that is implemented in all involved programming languages. Maybe Google's protobuf. Or if your data is text data, use JSON or XML.

Comment: It's not just endianness. It follows the contract of DataInput. That way, `readInt` always reads 4 bytes for an int. `readFloat` always reads 4 bytes. The endianness is also always specified.